# BBB - Automatically load a Device Tree overlay on boot

Tags: beagleboard, gpio, angstrom-linux, device-tree

I have a device tree overlay:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "ti,beaglebone", "ti,beaglebone-black";
    part-number = "mousetraps";
    version = "00A1";

    /* https://github.com/derekmolloy/boneDeviceTree/blob/master/docs/BeagleboneBlackP9HeaderTable.pdf */
    fragment@0 {
            target = <&am33xx_pinmux>;
            __overlay__ {
                    mousetrap_pins: pinmux_mousetrap_pins {
                            pinctrl-single,pins = <
                                    0x070 0x2f /* P9_11 30 INPUT MODE7 none */
                                    0x074 0x2f /* P9_13 31 INPUT MODE7 none */
                                    0x040 0x2f /* P9_15 48 INPUT MODE7 none */
                                    0x15c 0x2f /* P9_17 05 INPUT MODE7 none */
                            >;
                    };
            };
    };

    fragment@1 {
            target = <&ocp>;
            __overlay__ {
                    test_helper: helper {
                            compatible = "bone-pinmux-helper";
                            pinctrl-names = "default";
                            pinctrl-0 = <&mousetrap_pins>;
                            status = "okay";
                    };
            };
    };
};
```

which I can successfully load with:

```
echo mousetraps:00A1 >/sys/devices/bone_capemgr.8/driver/bone_capemgr.8/slots ; dmesg | grep bone
```

How can I configure the BBB/Angstrom to load it automatically on boot?

More specifically, how can I hook the dtbo file into the normal Device Tree loading mechanism? I know I can add the echo to a linux init script, but it seems like there must be something that triggers the loading of the dtbo files.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this would be to copy the `dtbo` into `/lib/firmware` and modify `capemgr.extra_override` parameter in the kernel `bootargs` (in **uEnv.txt**) to point to the `dtbo` file. This technique also requires modifications to the `/arch/arm/boot/dts/am335-bone-common.dtsi` file. Details in this **[discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/beagleboard/jYpYHZPl1ig/90BPMxxhWLMJ)**.

Note that loading the device-tree overlay from the filesystem seems to be an issue specifically with the recent kernels(from the official repository) on the beaglebone black. To overcome this, an alternate method to compile the overlay is described **[here](http://hipstercircuits.com/enable-device-tree-overlay-on-startup-on-beaglebone-black/)**.

Comment: Regarding the issue with loading the device tree overlay at boot time—see [FBTFT BeagleBone Black—Enable overlay at boot](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/BeagleBone-Black#enable-overlay-at-boot).

Answer (score 3):

you may add an argument in the uEnv.txt
that refers to your new overlay as suggested previously 
add the following string to the end of the uEnv.txt

```
nano /mnt/boot/uEnv.txt

#add this to the end of the single line of uEnv.txt:

capemgr.enable_partno=mousetraps
```

[the full process is described here](http://learn.adafruit.com/introduction-to-the-beaglebone-black-device-tree/exporting-and-unexporting-an-overlay)

Comment: One thing you should not forget, when using Debian I needed to add the option to the capemgr file:
`nano /etc/default/capemgr`
And then in your situation, add:
`CAPE=mousetraps:00A1`

Ps. On a beaglebone the version is often: "00A0".

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with

- BeagleBone Black rev C
- Debian 8.7 2017-03-19 4GB SD IoT from [latest-images](https://beagleboard.org/latest-images)
- Kernel 4.4.68-ti-r106

From the [link provided](https://github.com/notro/fbtft/wiki/BeagleBone-Black#enable-overlay-at-boot) by @craig-mcqueen and using this [device tree overlay example](http://derekmolloy.ie/gpios-on-the-beaglebone-black-using-device-tree-overlays/)

In the `/boot/uboot/uEnv.txt` file (DM-GPIO-Test is the name of my overlay):

```
cmdline=coherent_pool=1M cape_universal=enable bone_capemgr.enable _partno=DM-GPIO-Test noapic
```

Create `/etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/dtbo`

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
. /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions

# Copy Device Tree fragments
mkdir -p "${DESTDIR}/lib/firmware"
cp -p /lib/firmware/*.dtbo "${DESTDIR}/lib/firmware/"
```

Make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/dtbo
```

Backup initrd:

```
sudo cp /boot/initrd.img-4.4.68-ti-r106 /boot/initrd.img-4.4.68-ti-r106.bak
```

Update initrd:

```
/opt/scripts/tools/developers/update_initrd.sh
```

Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Check that it's been loaded:

```
root@beaglebone:/home/debian# cat /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots
0: PF----  -1 
1: PF----  -1 
2: PF----  -1 
3: PF----  -1 
4: P-O-L-   0 Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,DM-GPIO-Test
```